# Customize search block in frontpage

Tags: 7

I am using Zen3 theme , i created a subtheme ,i want have a big search box in front page , for doing this , i created  a front page template `page--front.tpl.php`.
also i added a custom css to my search-box by this code in `template.php`

```
function myrtheme_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array('#type' => 'image_button', '#src' => base_path() . path_to_theme() . '/images/search-icon.png');
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-icon';
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-box';
    }
```

my problem is how can add css class only to the frontpage in `page--front.tpl.php`.

Comment: Zen, like many other themes, provides body classes. You could use `body.front {}` to target the front page only.

Comment: @Webdrips can you explain more ?

Comment: @alireza  "add css class only to the frontpage " you mean want add class  to search block in only front page?

Comment: @zhilevan yes , i want have two different search block on my website one big on front page and one small on other pages.that all i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `drupal_is_front_page()` to check it is on front page or not. You can achieve it using code similar to the following.

```
function myrtheme_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array('#type' => 'image_button', '#src' => base_path() . path_to_theme() . '/images/search-icon.png');
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'fpage-search-icon';
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'fpage-search-box';
  }
  else {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'other-page-search-icon';
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'other-page-search-box';
  }
}
```